# typeof EnforceAjax is not assignable to type Middleware

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following class and interface:

```
export class EnforceAjax implements Middleware {
  public handle(client: Client) {
    return client.ajax === true
  }
}

export interface Middleware {
  handle?(client: Client, ...args: any[]): boolean | Response
}
```

When I try to execute the following:

```
Router.group('/api', { middleware: [EnforceAjax] }, async () => require('./api'))


export interface RouterOptions {
  middleware?: (Middleware | string)[]
}

public static group(routePrefix: string, options: RouterOptions, callback: Function): void
```

I get the following error:

> Type 'typeof EnforceAjax' is not assignable to type 'string | Middleware'.
>     Value of type 'typeof EnforceAjax' has no properties in common with type 'Middleware'. Did you mean to call it?

The error goes away when I add the `new` keyword though however I don't want to pass an instance of the class as a value into the array.

Comment: Well, the static methods of `EnforceAjax` don't match the interface `Middleware`, only the *instance* methods do. So yeah, you'll want to pass an instance.

Comment: The value `EnforceAjax` is not a `Middleware`, it's a constructor that produces a `Middleware` when `new`ed.  If you intend `EnforceAjax` to be a `Middleware` maybe you want `handle()` to be `static`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then type `middleware` as a Middleware constructor:

```
 export interface RouterOptions {
   middleware?: ({ new(): Middleware; } | string)[]
 }
```

Not sure why you need a class at all though.

Comment: I am using a class because some of the Middleware classes can be a little more complex.